# Firebase receive object with only one specific value React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, listener, native

Lets say I have a firebase database like this:

```
Events 
    -Name "Some name"
    -message "simple message"
    -visible "1"

and
    -Name "Some name"
    -message "simple message"
    -visible "0"
```

Now I only want to read all the objects with the value visible 0 if visible = 1 then it may not be displayed in a list.

How can I achieve this?

With my current code I get all the current data from the firebase (Event)
But I only want to get all the values if there is a visible 0 inside.

In my view code this is where I read all the data:

```
    <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>
          {this.props.task.Event.visible}</Text>                 
        <Text>{this.props.task.Event.name}</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.task.Event.message}</Text>
    </View>
```

Is there something that I can say like if this.props.task.Event.visible = 0 then ... 
else ...?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you store your data. What you can do is place all visible events in a `visible` object and all non-visible events in the `invisible` object.

So your data structure could look like this:

```
Events
    -visible
        -Name ""Some name
        -message "simple message"

    -invisible
        -Name ""Some name
        -message "simple message"
```

Of course you'll have to use the `.push()` function this way you have a unique identifier for the event.